# generating HTML on server for conversion api

Tags: google-app-engine

I am looking into the converstion api to generate pdf documents from HTML.
I have lot of complex HTML that should be generated dynamically.  What is the best way to generate complex HTML on appengine server so that, I can use it in the conversion api.

Asset asset = new Asset(
    "text/html", "some data".getBytes(), "testfile.html");

In the above the second param is the HTML.  What if I have complex HTML? What is a good way to generate the HTML, so that it is maintainable and readable.

-Aswath

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to generate some complex HTML and also going to inject some data into it, some templating engine ([Velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014099/velocity-framework-on-google-app-engine), [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) or any other) would be useful here.

On the other side if you want to prepare some nice looking and readable template in a quick way, I suggest you using Google Docs for it. App Engine's Conversion API and Google Docs "Export as PDF" feature share the same backend, so you can easily edit the template in Google Docs, then use "Export as HTML" feature to get the HTML, using it with GAE conversion API you will get the same result as if you'd download it as PDF in Google Docs.